# Starting point for a tile map

Tags: java, 2d, java-2d, tile

I am due to start work on a 2D platform game in Java using Java2D, and am trying to devise a way to create a world. I have been reading up about this for the last few hours now, and as far as I can tell, a relatively effective way is to have a text file with a "matrix" of values in it, which is read in by the program in order to create the map (stored in a 2D array).

Now, my plan is to have multiple JComponents that display ImageIcons for the various textures in the world; the JComponent object would depend on the character in the given array index.

1. Is there anything I may have overlooked?
2. Will this schematic work with a background image, i.e. when there is a character that represents a blank space, will part of the background be shown?

Apologies if this seems like a lazy question, I can assure you it is not out of laziness. I am merely trying to plan this out before hacking code together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have compelling reason to, having a different component for each tile is probably not a good way to go.  Look into a Canvas and displaying loaded images at different offsets in it.

Example:
480x640 Canvas
128x16 image file(contains 8 16x16 tile images)
So your file has a bunch of numbers(characters etc.), we'll say 0-7 for the 8 tiles in the image.  The file has 30x40 numbers, laid out in a grid the same as the canvas.  So

1 2 1 3 4 8 2...
...

And to display the code ends up something like(not tested, based on [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29))

```
Graphics g = //initialize graphics;
Image yourTileImage = //load your image;
for (int xpos = 0; xpos < maxX; xpos++)
    for (int ypos = 0; ; ypos < maxY; ypos++)
        int number = //get number from map file
        g.drawImage(Image yourTileImage,
            xpos * 16, ypos * 16, xpos * 16 + 15, ypos * 16 + 15,
            number*16, 0, number+15, 15,
            ImageObserver observer)
```

Which basically maps the number to your tile image, then puts that tile image into the right spot in the canvas(x,y) coordinates * size of tile.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response. I have seen what you have done here and it seems logical, thanks. However, I was intending on having the tiles as separate components, so that I can write in my own methods for collision detection. Also, I could repaint a single object.

Comment: Will this be possible by extending the Image class?

Comment: This is just a method to display the world.  Collision detection etc. should probably deal with the actual coordinates instead of the displayed ones and thus be unrelated to the method used for presentation.  As an additional note, if you're using Swing instead of awt you want to look at JPanel instead of Canvas.

If by repaint you mean the screen refresh, then yes, the whole Canvas here would refresh.  If you mean that you want to be able to change what's being drawn to part of the screen, you'll have to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of good 2d graphics engines available for Java. You would be better off using one of those rather than trying to re-invent the wheel. (Quite apart from anything else they will make use of the GPU.

You should easily find one that does what you need.